# CakePHP 3 missing routes in nested routes setup

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to connect nested routes in CakePHP 3.

I am trying to achieve the following routes (in brackets their current state):

```
GET /api/users/:id/events     (Working)
POST /api/users/:id/events    (Missing Route)

GET /api/events/:id           (Working)
PATCH /api/events/:id         (Missing Route)
DELETE /api/events/:id        (Not tested)
```

In my routes.php file I have the following:

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/token', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'token']);

    $routes->resources('Users', function ($routes) {
        $routes->resources('Events', [
            'only' => ['index', 'add']
        ]);
    });

    $routes->resources('Events', [
        'only' => ['view', 'patch', 'delete']
    ]);
});
```

The routes that aren't working throws a `Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingRouteException`

The error page also shows a list of connected routes and the ones I would like is not present. Is it possible to create nested resources in the way I have tried or how would I be able to connect the desired routes without manually connecting each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look at the docs again, there are no `add` or `patch` values that the `only` option would support, not unless you'd add custom routes with these names to the default resource map.

By default only the following resource routes are supported:

- `index` (= `GET`)
- `view` (= `GET` with `/:id`)
- `create` (= `POST`)
- `update` (= `PUT` and `PATCH` with `/:id`)
- `delete` (= `DELETE` with `/:id`)

So what you want to use is `index` and `create` for the nested `Users/Events` resource routes, and `view`, `update` and `delete` for the non-nested `Events` resource routes.

See also

- [**Cookbook > Routing > Creating RESTful Routes > Limiting the Routes Created**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#limiting-the-routes-created)
- [**Cookbook > Routing > Creating RESTful Routes > Mapping Additional Resource Routes**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#mapping-additional-resource-routes)

Comment: I completely missed the route names. I wonder where I got those route names from. So just to make sure, the `create` route name would be connected to the `add` action in the controller. Same with `update` and `edit`. Patch is a complete miss here.